# Excel Worksheet_Change not working when macro changes cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm trying to finish up a project of mine and I right now have a Form Control that when pressed adds to the value of a number and another button will subtract that value.

Another value has the two different buttons for the same thing, but the value is also dependent on the first value and other things than just the buttons modify that value.  I tried implementing this code for validation

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("F19")) Is Nothing Then
 If Range("E19") = 2 And Range("F19") < 12 Then
  Range("E20") = 1
 End If
End If
End Sub
```

but Excel apparently doesn't recognize that cell F19 has changed when the change is caused by the button, only when it is caused by user input.  So, what this is saying is, if F19 updates and 19 is 2 and F19 is less than 12 (the prerequisite for E12 being 2 is F19 being 12 or greater) then set E20 to 1 (E20 is a modifier for E19 which also has other modifiers going into it).  This method works on other values that aren't button controlled, but how can I get excel to realize when the Form Control button changes the value (or at least monitor when the form control is pressed.)

Edit: The macro actually doesn't work if the cell changes by formula either.  I don't think I can use Worksheet_Calculate to monitor the change in a specific cell.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this with code anyway? You could have Cell E20 have a formula like: `=IF(AND(E19=2,F19<12),1,"")` which would make the cell blank unless the condition is met.

If you really want to do it with code, you should take this into account: The [Worksheet_Change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) "Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link."

I would recommend instead of having

```
If Range("E19") = 2 And Range("F19") < 12 Then
    Range("E20") = 1
End If
```

In your Worksheet_Change event that you add it as a separate sub, that you call from Worksheet_Change. You would also call the sub from the code for your button, after you've performed whatever action your button does. That way, you're guaranteed the check gets run and do not try to rely on events.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is partialy right, `Worksheet_Change` "Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link."  But this *includes* changes caused by VBA, and *Excludes* changes by a formula.

Your problem may be caused (or at least exacerbated) by the only partial qualification of your ranges:

`Range("E19")` will refer to 'E19' *on the active sheet*, which may or may not be be the sheets `Target` is on.  You got it right with `Target.Worksheet.Range("F19")`

Try (note the `.`'s)

```
With Target.Worksheet
    If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("F19")) Is Nothing Then
        If .Range("E19") = 2 And .Range("F19") < 12 Then
            .Range("E20") = 1
        End If
    End If
End With
```

BTW. I'm with Daniel in that your whole solution seems a little off, but we may not be getting the whole picture...

Comment: I don't think that's right.  My understanding is that an unqualified range reference in a standard module will refer to the activesheet.  But an unqualified range reference in a sheet's class module will refer to that sheet.  I do agree that the OP should fully qualify the range references to avoid any confusion.  The OP might also consider the Me keyword.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't tell me I was wrong in a comment on my answer. Oh well. I just believed MSDN without bothering to test it. I removed my offending sentence. :) Thanks